# Problem to compile a C-program by GCC in the latest Cygwin due to tgmath.h and complex.h

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compiler-construction, cygwin

I have successfully compiled a C-program with `GCC` in Mac OS X and Linux, but have got the following error message in Cygwin 1.7.5:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/include/tgmath.h:38:21: error: complex.h: No 
such file or directory
```

I have noticed that several guys reported that tgmath.h has problems in Cygwin. However, due to the lack of knowledge I cannot understand if those issues have been already fixed or if they are related to the error I get. See, for example:

1. http://cygwin.com/ml/libc-alpha/1999-12/msg00021.html
2. http://cygwin.com/ml/libc-hacker/2007-07/msg00012.html

As an experiment, my colleagues have replaced `include <tgmath.h>` with `include <math.h>`. However, the code threw an exception.

Could you explain me what can be wrong in Cygwin's `tgmath.h` or `complex.h`, and how I can get through it?

Answer (score 0):

This could completely wrong, but make sure you're compiling with `-std=c99`, complex.h is part of the C99 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the complex.h stuff hasn't been implemented for Cygwin (or more precisely, for newlib, which is the C library used by Cygwin).

http://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/std-notimpl.html